# Select amount with Paypal donation button

Tags: paypal

I try to create donate via PayPal button and add custom select with amount.
I tried to add something like this:

```
<label for="amount">Select the amount you wish to donate:</label>
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR" />
<select id="amount" name="amount">
  <option value="25.00">€25.00</option>
  <option value="35.00">€35.00</option>
  <option value="50.00">€50.00</option>
  <option value="75.00">€75.00</option>
  <option value="100.00">€100.00</option>
</select>
```

but PayPal simply doesn't recieve selected value.
What I'm missing?
What custom variables should I put into button generator form?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This code works for me:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">

<!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments. -->
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="my@email.com">

<!-- Specify a Donate button. -->
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_donations">

<!-- Specify details about the contribution -->
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Donation">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="Donation"> 
<select name="amount"><option value="10.00">€10.00</option><option value="25.00">€25.00</option></select>
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">

<!-- Display the payment button. -->
<input type="image" name="submit" border="0" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donate_LG.gif" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online">
</form>
```

[Reference](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_donation_buttons#id08AAF0T10ZS)

Comment: Thanks. It works perfectly. I guess error was caused by input "hosted_button_id"